# How to install debian9 with ppp-udeb?

Tags: system-installation, debian-installer

Here is the way i want to install debian9 and ppp-udeb.
1.download debian9 iso file,save as debian9.iso.
2. dd if=debian9.iso  of=/dev/sdb
3.set boot as usb  in my bios
4.the install gui
[image]
5.press e
[image]
6.add  `install modules=ppp-udeb`
[image]

7.failure!
[image]

How to install debian9 with ppp-udeb ?

Comment: Is your question:  **How can I install Debian using an image file copied to a USB stick?**

Comment: How can I install Debian at the same time to install the ppp-udeb using an image file copied to a USB stick?